# How to handle YUV422 (YUYV) image as input of a CNN?

Tags: machine-learning, keras, computer-vision, conv-neural-network

I want to feed an image that is stored in the YUV422 (YUYV) format into a CNN. YUV422 means that two pixels are represented by four bytes, basically two pixels share the chroma but have separate luminances.

I understand that for convolutional neural networks the spatiality plays an important role, i.e. that the filters "see" the luminance pixels together with their corresponding chroma pixels. So how would one approach this problem? Or is this no problem at all?

I want to avoid an additional preprocessing step for performance reasons.

Comment: I have read this paper on the issue: YUVMultiNet: Real-time YUV multi-task CNN for autonomous driving https://arxiv.org/pdf/1904.05673.pdf. Did you manage to solve the problem? If yes please share

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convolutional Neural Networks as implemented in common frameworks like TensorFlow, PyTorch, etc. stores channels in a planar fashion. That is, each channel (R,G,B or Y,U,V) is stored in a continuous region with all the pixels in the image (width x height). This in contrast to the format where channel data are interleaved inside each pixel. So you will need to upsample the subsampled UV channels to match the size of the Y channel, and then feed it to the network in the same way as RGB data.

Others have found it to work OK, but not reaching the performance of RGB. See https://github.com/ducha-aiki/caffenet-benchmark/blob/master/Colorspace.md
and [Effect of image colourspace on performance of convolution neural networks](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8256949) by K Sumanth Reddy; Upasna Singh; Prakash K Uttam.

It is unlikely that the YUV to RGB conversion would be a bottleneck. RGB has the distinct advantage that one can reuse many excellent pretrained models (transfer learning).

Answer (score 1):

### 1

In this paper [YUVMultiNet: Real-time YUV multi-task CNN for autonomous driving](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/YUVMultiNet%3A-Real-time-YUV-multi-task-CNN-for-Boulay-El-Hachimi/b01b58e5a0deea14270dd2505478675f0b63f15b), channel **Y and UV are are fed into different conv sperately**.

[image]
[image]

### 2 RGB v.s. YUV  v.s.  HSV  v.s.  Lab (1)

As mentioned by Jon Nordby，[here](https://github.com/ducha-aiki/caffenet-benchmark#tocbar--tjef2t) shows a comparison.
Interestingly, the learned RGB2GRAY method is better than that in openCV.
YCbCr seems to underperform RGB. The experiment is conducted on ImageNet-2012.
I will Try it on COCO or other datasets later

[image]

### 3. RGB v.s. YUV  v.s.  HSV  v.s.  Lab (2)

In paper *Deep leaning approach with colorimetric spaces and vegetation indices for vine diseases detection in UAV images*，YUV is generally better than RGB.

RGB and YUV color spaces have obtained the best performances in terms of discrimination between the four classes.

RGB:
remains sensitive to the size of the CNN’s convolution filter, especially for patches size (64x64).

The HSV and LAB color spaces have performed less than other color spaces.

For HSV:
this is mainly due to the Hue (H) channel that **contains all color information grouped into a single channel** which is less relevant for network to learn **best color features** from this color space. It is the color that has the most relevance in the classification, the saturation and value channels did not make a good contribution to the classification.

For the LAB color space:
classification results were **not conclusive.** This may be due to that a and b channels,
does **not represent effectively the colors related to the diseased vineyard**. The L-channel contributes little to the classification because it represents the quantity of light the color space.

From the results, that YUV is more **stable and consistent** which makes it more suitable for symptoms detection. These good performances are related to the color information of the **green colour corresponding to healthy vegetation**, and the **brown and yellow colours characterising diseased** vegetation, presented in **UV channels**.

The combination of different spaces produced lower scores than each space separately except a slight improvement for (16 1 × 6) patch.
This is due to the fact that CNN has not been able to extract **good color features from multiple channels** for discriminating healthy and diseased classes

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).